# Unix Shell create multiple directories and random files(empty) inside

Tags: linux, shell, unix, directory

I'm trying to creating  multiple directories and random files(empty) inside with 1 shell script.
So far i have this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# creating dirs and files

mkdir /home/firro/opdrachta_1
```

I searched on the web for scripts but couldn't find any.

I hope someone is able to help me.

Comment: You can use `$RANDOM` as a random number. Try `mkdir $RANDOM`, then `ls -lrt` to see the latest, newest directory.

Comment: Wow thankyou! @MarkSetchell one more question, do you know how to also add random files in the directories created with this script? .txt for example

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10} ; do
    d=$RANDOM
    mkdir $d
    for j in {1..5} ; do
        e=$RANDOM
        echo Making $d/$e
        touch $d/$e
    done
done
```

It makes 10 random directories with 5 random files in each.

**Output**

```
Making 4708/295
Making 4708/9380
Making 4708/3763
Making 4708/30786
Making 4708/29234
Making 17143/15029
Making 17143/21649
Making 17143/29789
Making 17143/19491
Making 17143/21911
Making 23298/9658
Making 23298/19967
Making 23298/30776
Making 23298/13856
Making 23298/18724
Making 30923/12215
Making 30923/31772
Making 30923/10526
Making 30923/16091
Making 30923/25009
Making 9301/19563
Making 9301/17151
Making 9301/14391
Making 9301/18858
Making 9301/22637
Making 16821/20881
Making 16821/17792
Making 16821/15678
Making 16821/24846
Making 16821/12214
Making 28562/1936
Making 28562/4960
Making 28562/9094
Making 28562/3707
Making 28562/29765
Making 30897/12237
Making 30897/17669
Making 30897/8653
Making 30897/27358
Making 30897/8184
Making 2095/31555
Making 2095/8335
Making 2095/20117
Making 2095/27136
Making 2095/14663
Making 4827/22412
Making 4827/17678
Making 4827/5273
Making 4827/4538
Making 4827/12831
```